# I wanted to rewrite my project in typescript, but there is a problem in the App.tsx file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, jsx, eslint

I have ESLint errors that occur in the App.js file, which is created automatically when compiling my App.tsx, which contains a simple component. How to solve this problem?
There is an error example:

> [eslint]
> src/App.js
> Line 1:1:    'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules
> Line 1:1:    Strings must use singlequote

App.tsx:

```js
export default function App() { return <div>it works!</div> }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/@types"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_gallery",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.36.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.15",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: To solve your problem, I would start with a smaller `Example.tsx` with **zero** imports and `export default function Example() { return <div>it works!</div> }`. If you're still having issues, you should edit your question and include your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`

Comment: It's generally advised that each post on StackOverflow show include *one* focused question. The secondary question in your post is in regards to the `.js` files generated by typescript. These build artifacts are intended to be used as-is and _not_ included in your TS or ESLint config.

Comment: Btw, check out [Biome](https://biomejs.dev), a modern tool chain that gracefully replaces the common `prettier`+`eslint` bloatware.

Comment: yes, I still have this problem and after simplifying this component, I will upload the config files! Thank you

Comment: Your `tsconfig.json` file should have `"noEmit": true` inside `compilerOptions`. You don't have the TypeScript compiler generate JavaScript files when you have bundler set up (which in this case is Webpack)

Comment: @2022.A Check out [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib), you'll probably want `lib: ["DOM"]` to include the DOM module

Comment: @AliNauman good guess! But that didn't help much. Errors still appear

Comment: @Mulan my project is built with problems, but if I close this red window, I can see my project as a whole. But this is not a complete solution, right?

Comment: a successful build shouldn't have errors ;) are you getting a new error message?

Comment: @Mulan yes, even after all the recommendations from Stackoverflow users :) the problem is in ESLint, I think. I can manually fix the automatically collected App.js, but I shouldn’t go there, as I understand it

Comment: If you've changed all your source .JS files to TS, remove the ones generated by the TypeScript compiler. Then you can run `npx tsc` and `npx eslint src` to get a list of all the errors that are reported by these tools. Then you either fix them, or change the eslint/tsc config to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

set your `tsconfig.json` to this, it should fix your issues

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution":"node",
  },
  "moduleResolution":"node",
}
```

Comment: tried it, didn't work...